# Is there any way to get LLBLGen Pro to generate the generic and dbspecific .csproj files in separate directories

Tags: nuget, llblgenpro

`LLBLGen Pro` by default generates the `generic` and `db specific` project files in the same root directory.

I'm trying to make my model projects use `NuGet` for dependancy management and this breaks/starts behaving strangely as both projects end up referencing the same `packages.config`

As such I'm hoping there is a way to make `LLBLGen Pro` generate the project files in separate directories....

Any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the tasks in the preset, on tab 3 of the code generation configuration dialog. The tasks for the vs.net project files, e.g. 'SD.Tasks.Adapter.VsNetDbGenericProjectFileCreator' contain the destinationFolder property which is empty by default (so it generates into the root folder you specify).

It might become tricky though with the paths inside the vs.net project file, but you should start there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of a hack, but I had the same issue and because I had the same references in both the regular and the DbSpecific project I ended up installing the packages in the main project (so the packages.config got associated with that project) and then manually referencing the assemblies from the packages directory in the DBSpecific project (so the hint paths got setup properly).

Not the best solution, but at least you don't have to modify the default behavior of the genpro configuration.